# Python 3.11 and pyside 6, multiple inheritance

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside, pyside6

Behavior i dont understand, since we are passed from pyqt4 to pyside6

```
class Girl(QtCore.QObject):
  def __init__(self, genre="women"):
    QtCore.QObject.__init__(self)
    self.genre = genre

class Student(QtCore.QThread, Girl):
  def __init__(self, fname, lname):
    QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)    

  def printname(self):
    print(f"genre: {self.genre}")
  


x = Student("Mike", "Olsen")
x.printname()
```

I got the following error on the line QtCore.QThread.**init**(self)

> RuntimeError: You can't initialize an PySide6.QtCore.QThread object in
> class Student twice!

and i dont understand why.

If I had put this I would have understood:

```
class Student(QtCore.QThread, Girl):
  def __init__(self, fname, lname):
    Girl.__init__(self)
    QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)
```

because the QObject would have already been initialized via Girl constructor

why don't I reproduce the same error with the following code?

```
class Person(QtCore.QObject):
  def __init__(self, fname, lname):
    QtCore.QObject.__init__(self)
    self.firstname = fname
    self.lastname = lname

  def printname(self):
    print(self.firstname, self.lastname)

class Girl(QtCore.QObject):
  def __init__(self, genre="women"):
    QtCore.QObject.__init__(self)
    self.genre = genre

class Student2(Person, Girl):
  def __init__(self, fname, lname):
    Person.__init__(self, fname, lname)

  def printname(self):
    print(f"genre: {self.genre}")
  
x = Student2("Mike", "Olsen")
x.printname()
```

Comment: As much as I could debug, QtThread constructor calls Girl constructor as well. The reason I couldn't debug further is that the implementation of QThread is in c++ and I used a python debugger. Interesting question!

Comment: This is clearly a bug in PySide. When you override `__init__`, you must explicitly call ***all*** the base-class constructors yourself (or simply call `super().__init__()` in every base-class `__init__`). Python will only automatically initialise all the base-classes if you ***don't*** override `__init__`. In your original example, if you replace the PySide classes with some dummy plain Python classes, an attribute-error will be raised, because `Girl.__init__` will never be called (which is the correct and expected behaviour). Using `super` will fix that (but it won't fix the PySide bug).

Comment: It should also be pointed out that the vast majority of Qt classes aren't designed for multiple inheritance, so you should avoid doing that in PyQt/PySide code. It *might* work in some cases, but generally speaking you are asking for trouble unless you *really* know what you're doing. If you need to use mixin classes, it's best to use a plain Python `object` subclass, and then put it *first* in the base-class list and use `super`. (See e.g. [Support for Cooperative Multi-inheritance](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt6/multiinheritance.html) in the PyQt docs).

Comment: I remember a couple of reports bugreports.qt.io regarding these issues (including a regression after an attempt to solve the problem), but it should also be noted that subclassing from QThread *and* QObject is conceptually wrong, since QThread already inherits from QObject. This is also a requirement in C++, as explained in the docs: [Multiple Inheritance Requires QObject to Be First](//doc.qt.io/qt-6/moc.html#multiple-inheritance-requires-qobject-to-be-first), "be sure that only the first inherited class is a QObject."; while the order *may not* be an issue in the python bindings (since Qt ->

Comment: -> does not really know about the other python classes, so you can use a mixin with the python class first, in order to override some methods), this may be a problem in PySide and is also a problem in *any* case when using multiple inheritance of Qt classes (python classes that wrap Qt classes): the problem remains, if you ignore the order requirement, you can read the above phrase as "be sure that only **one** inherited class is a QObject". So, the solution is to use mixins and **always** use `super()` for all methods in any class, including those that will be inherited.

Comment: @musicamante It's actually the other way around: PySide2 has problems if a Python `object` mixin is placed *last* (i.e. the mixin `__init__` isn't called when using `super`). I think some previous verions of PyQt may have had similar issues. For the current versions of PyQt5, PyQt6 and PySide6, the ordering of `object` mixins doesn't (or shouldn't) matter. This is at least partly to allow support for e.g. slot decoration and signal declaration in `object` mixins, which PyQt certainly hasn't always supported, but PySide has.

Comment: @ekhumoro Yeah, sorry, I don't correctly remember the whole combined history of changes about that matter. But you're properly pointing out the issue (I know for a fact that, at least since 5.7, inheritance order doesn't normally create problems with mixins) and you also confirm what said above: only *one* inherited subclass type should be based on QObject. Which, logically speaking, makes sense, even in Python terms.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you encounter the error in the first case (with QThread and Girl classes) but not in the second case (with Person and Girl classes) lies in the difference in the inheritance hierarchy and the way Python handles multiple inheritance.

In the first case, the Student class inherits from both QThread and Girl. When you initialize Student, it tries to initialize both QThread and Girl since they are both inherited. However, QThread is already being initialized by the class itself, hence the error about initializing QThread twice. You can resolve this by calling the constructors of both base classes explicitly, ensuring that Girl is initialized before QThread, which is what you've done in the corrected code.

In the second case, Student2 inherits from both Person and Girl. However, there's no inherent conflict because neither Person nor Girl are themselves initialized twice within the Student2 class. When you call Student2("Mike", "Olsen"), it only initializes Person, and Girl is not explicitly initialized in the Student2 class, hence no conflict arises.

So, to summarize, the error occurs due to the order of initialization in the inheritance hierarchy and how Python handles multiple inheritance. In the corrected code, you've resolved it by explicitly initializing both base classes in the correct order.

Have you thought of this way